# Find 2nd and 3rd highest value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have below data frame of food items and its nutrient contents as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir('D:\\userdata\\adbharga\\Desktop\\AVA\\RTestCode\\Python')
data=pd.read_csv("nutrient.csv")
data.head()
```

Out[30]:

```
Name  Calories  Fat  Carb  Fiber  Protein
0      Chonga Bagel       300    5    50      3       12
1      8-Grain Roll       380    6    70      7       10
2  Almond Croissant       410   22    45      3       10
3     Apple Fritter       460   23    56      2        7
4  Banana Nut Bread       420   22    52      2        6
```

Need to extract the Top Nutrient content and its value. For that used below code.

```
data['Top Nutrient'] = data[['Calories','Fat','Carb','Fiber','Protein']].idxmax(axis=1)
data['Amount']= data[['Calories','Fat','Carb','Fiber','Protein']].max(axis=1)
data.head()
```

Out[33]:

```
Name  Calories  Fat  Carb  Fiber  Protein Top Nutrient  Amount
0      Chonga Bagel       300    5    50      3       12     Calories     300
1      8-Grain Roll       380    6    70      7       10     Calories     380
2  Almond Croissant       410   22    45      3       10     Calories     410
3     Apple Fritter       460   23    56      2        7     Calories     460
4  Banana Nut Bread       420   22    52      2        6     Calories     420
```

Is there a way to show next 2 Top Nutrient and its Value.Expected Output will be like this:

```
Name    NextTop2   NextTop2Amount
Chonga Bagel        Carb|Protein    50|12
8-Grain Roll        Carb|Protein    70|10
Almond Croissant    Carb|Fat        45|22
Apple Fritter       Carb|Fat        56|23
Banana Nut Bread    Carb|Fat        52|22
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best use [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) because very fast.

First filter columns by `subset` - `[]` and get indices by `argsort` for 2. and 3. top:

```
cols = ['Calories','Fat','Carb','Fiber','Protein']

arr = data[cols].values.argsort(axis=1)[:, [-2, -3]]
a = np.array(cols)[arr]
print (a)
[['Carb' 'Protein']
 ['Carb' 'Protein']
 ['Carb' 'Fat']
 ['Carb' 'Fat']
 ['Carb' 'Fat']]
```

Also select values by indices:

```
b = data[cols].values[np.arange(len(arr))[:,None], arr]
print (b)
[[50 12]
 [70 10]
 [45 22]
 [56 23]
 [52 22]]
```

Last create `DataFrame`s and add join by `|` for one column:

```
data['Top Nutrient'] = data[cols].idxmax(axis=1)
data['Amount']= data[cols].max(axis=1)
data['NextTop2'] = pd.DataFrame(a).apply('|'.join, 1)
data['NextTop2Amount'] = pd.DataFrame(b).astype(str).apply('|'.join, 1)
```

---

```
print (data)

               Name  Calories  Fat  Carb  Fiber  Protein Top Nutrient  Amount  \
0      Chonga Bagel       300    5    50      3       12     Calories     300   
1      8-Grain Roll       380    6    70      7       10     Calories     380   
2  Almond Croissant       410   22    45      3       10     Calories     410   
3     Apple Fritter       460   23    56      2        7     Calories     460   
4  Banana Nut Bread       420   22    52      2        6     Calories     420   

       NextTop2 NextTop2Amount  
0  Carb|Protein          50|12  
1  Carb|Protein          70|10  
2      Carb|Fat          45|22  
3      Carb|Fat          56|23  
4      Carb|Fat          52|22
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. In fact with little tweaking more results can be generated as per user requirement (like 1st and 3rd largest etc.)